# Refresh Listview updating from server

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm developing a `RSS` reader android app. I have a `ListView` that shows my feed. I'm using sax parser and rsshandler class to get feeds and then set my `ListView` with the feeds, this is done on my main activity `onCreate()` method.

Now I want to give the refresh button that will again fetch the feeds from the server and update my `ListView`. The question is how to call all those instructions again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On hit of refresh button start  fetching data in separate thread.  When data is read and
parsed,  make  it available to your list adapter via  appropriate method.  Do not forget to call  notifyDatasetChanged() method of your list adapter